# Cannot read property 'children' of undefined -- webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

[image]

Every time I update my component code, it throws `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, your question is extremely vague and doesn't provide enough useful information for someone to help you.  Some code snippets (e.g. your webpack config, and stack trace details of the error would be helpful).  Please read the following guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you applied the HMR plugin twice? For instance, if you're using the `webpack-dev-server` with the `--hot` option, you should **not** add the `HotModuleReplacement` in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: @jhnns Hi, appreciate your help. Here is my webpack config:

Comment: `if (__DEV__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for live development (HMR, NoErrors).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  )
} else if (__PROD__) {`   and Im using `https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit`